# Was Matt Damon’s casting in the Martian at all influenced by interstellar?

Tags: interstellar

In both the Martian and Interstellar Matt Damon plays a stranded astronaut who wants to get home. I realise that the roles are different, the movies are different and there is no in universe tie in.

But at any point did Ridley Scott comment on if Matt Damon’s role on Interstellar played any part in his casting.

Or Has Matt Damon talked about playing 2 such similar type roles back to back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an interview with [yahoo! Movies](https://uk.movies.yahoo.com/matt-damon-the-martian-is-totally-different-to-121752110156.html), Matt Damon said that he did The Martian in spite of his casting in Interstellar:

> I said, I really love this script, but my only hesitation is I’ve just
> done ‘Interstellar’, in which I played a dude stranded on a planet, it
> might be weird if, after taking a year and a half off, I played
> another dude stranded on a planet.
>
> I explained ‘Interstellar’ to him, and he said ‘The movies are totally
> f***ing different, this is going to be f***ing fun. Let’s do this!’ He
> was so infectious, I couldn’t really say no to him.”

Note that when Damon first expressed interest in The Martian, the director was supposed to be Drew Goddard (rather than Ridley Scott). [source](https://www.ign.com/articles/2015/06/17/matt-damon-explains-why-the-martian-is-a-love-letter-to-science)

Answer (score 5):

It seems pretty unlikely, given that *Interstellar* came first — it was a 2014 release and *The Martian* was 2015.

Comment: Or vice versa? Hmm?

Comment: And that shows I should have checked Wikipedia for my facts was convinced in my head interstellar came after will amend the question :)